# AWK command used for puting text from files to different file

Tags: awk

I have 2 text files. I supose to use awk command to put data from these two files into third group of files that I already created. I need from first file first 10 rows and from second first 20 rows to put in fileNo1,then from first file second 10 rows and  from second file second 20 rows in fileNo2 and to do like that until fileNo500.(I have 500 files where I shoud store data from first and second file and each of these final files will have 30 rows with data). How can I do this?

Comment: what did you do so far?  Why do you think `awk` is needed?

Comment: i just created 500 files. Professor said we must write awk script or use awk command....

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.